# How to programmatically update the selected resource for link-with-editor functionality?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My Eclipse plugin provides an editor which contains a list of files (as result of a dependency search). When the user selects a file in the list, this file/resource should be highlighted in package/resource explorer.

This could be done easily using the link-with-editor functionality of the explorer view if there was a call like: `updateSelectedResource(IResource)` that I could call from within my editor to explicity set the active file. What is the actual call?

Answer (score 3):

Your editor must become a [ISelectionProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ISelectionProvider.html). In the [Eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_make_a_view_respond_to_selection_changes_in_another_view%3F) you get a complete example, where the important line for registering your selection provider is `getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);`. Afterwards the selected file in your list is automatically told to all selection listeners, including the package explorer.

If you want to get the big picture about the selection service (which is responsible for making those views react on selections in other views), there is an [Eclipse article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html) describing it in detail.

And if find yourself wanting to interact with even more existing views, you may also want to have a look at IAdaptable, as described [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecllink/), but this is not necessary for the package explorer linking.

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems to point into the right direction. My class implements now `ISelectionProvider` and as far as I can say it seems to work in principle. But when I try to publish/fire a change by giving a `SelectionChangedEvent` (containing a structured selection) to `selectionChanged` on each listener that was added before using my impl of `ISelectionProvider.addSelectionChangedListener`, nothing happens. Somehow the resource explorer does not seem to recognize my event or it ignores it...

Comment: _You_ should not fire those events, I think. Your list needs to contain real IResource objects (and show them using a label provider), then your user interaction with the list should fire the necessary events automatically. My guess is that your list instead contains pure Strings (e.g. file names) only, might that be?

Comment: Almost. ;) My list contains my own/custom objects which work as a wrapper, storing an `IResource` plus additional data. This is because the resources in the list/treeview are the result of a dependency track/search. My meta data holds information on the context in which the searcher found the resource. Therefore even the same resource may appear multiple times in the list, but with different meta data.

Comment: The eclipse FAQ page should be http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_make_a_view_respond_to_selection_changes_in_another_view%3F

Comment: @im_chc: Thanks, fixed. Bad that I missed it here, even though I reported that bug in the parser myself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141841/hyperlink-editor-corrupts-urls-ending-in-encoded-question-marks